# Wrong behviour with nested chains in rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am completely new in rxjava, will be glad to receive help, thanks in advance. Here is fragment of my code working with retrofit getting json from rest api and chaining requests to construct collection of objects.

The scheme to obtain is as follows:

Get ArtObjectIds then for each id combine results from
ArtObjectInfo and tileLevels
(for one of tileLevels get its image tiles, combine bitmap from them, link that bitmap to tileLevel. This is what I can not achieve.)
into createArtObject from getArtObjectInfo and getImageTileLevels
and then work with List of ArtObjects.

The question is: how to update an object with results obtained from nested chain,
in my case link tileLevel to bitmap obtained from its nested tiles.

Here is code:

```
apiService.getArtObjectIds(author, page, num)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(ArtObjectsResponse::getArtObjectIds)
            .doOnNext(artObjectIds -> Log.d("RX_TESTS", artObjectIds.toString()))
            .flatMap((Function<List<String>, Observable<List<ArtObject>>>) artObjectIds -> {
                if (artObjectIds.size() > 0) {           
                    return Observable.fromIterable(artObjectIds)
                            .doOnNext(artObjectId -> Log.d(TAG, "Processing artObjectId  " + artObjectId))
                            .concatMap(artObjectId ->
                                    Observable.combineLatest(
                                            apiService.getArtObjectInfo(artObjectId)
                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .map(ArtObjectInfoResponse::getArtObjectInfo),
                                            apiService.getImageTileLevels(artObjectId)
                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .map(ImageTileLevelsResponse::getTileLevels)
                                                    .flatMap((Function<List<ImageTileLevel>, Observable<List<ImageTileLevel>>>) imageTileLevels -> {
                                                        for (ImageTileLevel tileLevel : imageTileLevels) {
                                                            if (tileLevel.suitsForPreview()) {
                                                                tileLevel.setPreview(true);
                                                                Observable.fromIterable(tileLevel.getTiles())
                                                                .concatMap(imageTile -> apiService.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlAsync(imageTile.getUrl()))
                                                                .toList()
                                                                
                                                                // Wrong behavior here: results of doOnSuccess are ignored.
                                                                // tileLevel is not updated.
                                                                
                                                                .doOnSuccess(responses -> {
                                                                    Log.d("TAG", "In do on success");
                                                                    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
                                                                    for (Response<ResponseBody> response : responses) {
                                                                        assert response.body() != null;
                                                                        bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream()));
                                                                    }
                                                                    tileLevel.combineBitmaps(bitmaps);
                                                                });
                                                                break;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        return  Observable.just(imageTileLevels);
                                                    }),
                                            ArtObject::createArtObject))
                            .doOnNext(artObject -> Log.d(TAG, "Finished processing artObject " + artObject.getId()))
                            .toList()
                            .doOnSuccess(artObjects -> Log.d(TAG, "Finished processing all artObjects"))
                            .toObservable();
                         
                } else {
                    return Observable.just(new ArrayList<>());
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(.....},
```

Comment: Please organize your lambdas into smaller methods, it is difficult to view it on StackOverflow in this deeply nested state. Otherwise, what I could gather is you map your object to its members so you lose that object down the line. Instead, keep the original object flowing and use its `getXXX` methods to extract members on the spot.

Comment: Thank you vey much! It works with keeping object flow and calling object's 'makeSomething' method. But if this method also makes requests that need to be chained, it will have its own chain with subscribe(). So there is subscribe inside subscribe. Is it inevitable in situations with "awkward" json api?